# Resized copy of Pytorch Tensor/Dataset

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a homemade dataset with a few million rows.   I am trying to make truncated copies.  So I clip the tensors that I'm using to make the original dataset and create a new dataset.   However, when I save the new dataset, which is only 20K rows, it's the same size on disk as the original dataset.  Otherwise everything seems kosher, including, when I check, the size of the new tensors.   What am I doing wrong?

```
#original dataset - 2+million rows
dataset = D.TensorDataset(training_data, labels)
torch.save(dataset, filename)

#20k dataset for experiments
d = torch.Tensor(training_data[0:20000])
l = torch.Tensor(labels[0:20000])
ds_small = D.TensorDataset(d,l)
#this is the same size as the one above on disk... approx 1.45GB
torch.save(ds_small, filename_small)
```

Thanks

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please consider marking it as the correct answer so that the question is no longer shown as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `d` and `training_data` share the same memory, even if you use slicing during the creation of `d`. I don't know why this is the case, but answer anyway to give you a solution:

```
d = x[0:10000].clone()
l = y[0:10000].clone()
```

`clone`will give you Tensors with a memory independent from the old Tensor's and the file size will be much smaller.

Note that using `torch.Tensor()` is not necessary when creating `d` and `l` since `training_data` and `labels` are already tensors.

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  The torcn.Tensor() was my attempt to force a deep copy.  I suspected it was a straightforward answer but my attempts came up empty.